# Chaining animations with AnimatedContent in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

[image: Rolling Digit]

I have implemented a simple `Composable` which animates the transition of a digit's value in the above fashion. A key aspect is for the animation to slow down towards the end (non uniform speed).

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun RollingDigit(
    targetDigit: Int,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    delay: Long = (Random.nextFloat() * 300).roundToLong(),
) {
    var animationDuration by remember { mutableStateOf(100L) }
    var targetOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Random.nextInt(15, 30)) }
    var currentDigit by remember { mutableStateOf(getSourceDigit(targetDigit, targetOffset)) }

    LaunchedEffect(targetDigit) {
        targetOffset = Random.nextInt(15, 30)
        animationDuration = 100L
        currentDigit = getSourceDigit(targetDigit, targetOffset)
        delay(delay)
        while (targetOffset > 0) {
            targetOffset--
            animationDuration += ((10 - targetOffset) * 10L).coerceAtLeast(0L)
            currentDigit = (currentDigit + 1) % 10
            delay(animationDuration)
        }
    }

    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = currentDigit,
        transitionSpec = {
            slideInVertically(
                animationSpec = tween(animationDuration.toInt()),
                initialOffsetY = { -it },
            ) with slideOutVertically(
                animationSpec = tween(animationDuration.toInt()),
                targetOffsetY = { it }
            )
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "$it",
            style = textStyle,
        )
    }
}

private fun getSourceDigit(targetDigit: Int, targetOffset: Int): Int {
    val difference = (targetDigit - targetOffset) % 10
    return if (difference < 0) difference + 10 else difference
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun StackOverflowExample() {
    RollingDigit(
        targetDigit = 1,
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
    )
}
```

In essence, the animation works by setting a value for `currentDigit` inside `LaunchedEffect`, and the `AnimatedContent` composable which has a reference to `currentDigit` is recomposed, leading to the 'slot machine' like animation. In order to provide enough time for the animation to complete before assigning the next value for `currentDigit`, I have added the `delay` function inside the `LaunchedEffect` as well.

My concern with the above code is that it does not feel very robust to rely on the animation to finish during the duration of `delay`. I was hoping that we could solve this by chaining the animations so that the next animation is only started after the previous one finishes. I would imagine that if there is some way of using callbacks on the animation finishing or being able to launch the animation using a suspend function inside the `LaunchedEffect` would solve the problem but I'm not aware of any methods to do this. Alternative suggestions on possible implementation would be appreciated as well!

Comment: chaining your animations manually will just make it more complex, a delay is enough for the use case as the numbers are changed automatically and not after a button click or something by the user

Comment: Thanks #220284, your code snippet is helping me to sort out an issue related to the slot machine kind of animation

Comment: Glad it could help, I'm still not convinced it's a good way of implementing the animation though!